# Oracle Stored Procedure returning collection of table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to write a procedure using collections.

I have a table - `employee` -  and I want to return the following:

- **TEST1:** count of employees whose sal < 10000
- **TEST2:** count of employees whose dept > 10
- **TEST3:** count of employees whose hiredate >(SYSDATE-60)
- **TEST4:** count of employees whose grade = 1

My final recordset or array table should return below values. TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4 are description values residing in DESCRIPTION TABLE where as count values are from employee table.

```
Description   COUNT
TEST1         10 
TEST2         15
TEST3         25
TEST4         50
```

Please help with implementation.

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please update your question with sample SQL code you have written for each of the TESTS.

Answer (score 3):

This solution won't use your `DESCRIPTION` table to calculate counts dynamically, as that would be rather hard to achieve. So, here's a solution with hard-coded `TESTn` descriptions.

First, create the record type:

```
CREATE TYPE count_t AS OBJECT (
  description varchar2(100),
  cnt NUMBER(10)
);
```

Then, create the table type:

```
CREATE TYPE count_tt AS TABLE OF count_t;
```

Now, write the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION counts RETURN count_tt
IS
  v_result count_tt;
BEGIN
  SELECT count_t(description, cnt)
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_result
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      count(CASE WHEN sal < 10000 THEN 1 END) TEST1,
      count(CASE WHEN dept > 10 THEN 1 END) TEST2,
      count(CASE WHEN hiredate > SYSDATE - 60 THEN 1 END) TEST3,
      count(CASE WHEN grade = 1 THEN 1 END) TEST4
    FROM employees
  ) t
  -- Behold, the power of unpivot!
  UNPIVOT (
    cnt FOR description IN ("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST4")
  );

  RETURN v_result;
END counts;
/
```

Now, call the function, e.g. from SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(counts)
```

Enjoy.

By the way, I've written up a blog post [comparing this solution from a performance perspective with others that do not use `UNPIVOT`](http://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/18/impress-your-coworkers-by-using-sql-unpivot/)